# Cannot open Scene Builder in IntelliJ for MaterialFX demo project

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, built-in, materialfx

I have downloaded the following project to see how the demo application works:

https://github.com/palexdev/MaterialFX

I can successfully build and run it, I can use the demo app, and see all the features it has.

The problem is when I want to edit the .fxml files with the **built-in Scene Builder** in **IntelliJ**:
[image]

What and how should I set it up to be able to edit with it? I think I could edit it with the separate Scene Builder app but I would prefer to do it with the built-in one.

Cheers!

Comment: "the separate Scene Builder app but I don't want to pay for it" -> The [standalone Scene Builder application](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/#download) is free.  You could choose to pay for a support subscription if you wanted to, but you don't have to if you don't want or need it.

Comment: If you are using the in-built SceneBuilder in Idea, then make sure you have the very latest Idea version, at least 2021.3, otherwise (and perhaps even still), [SceneBuilder in Idea doesn't work well](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-266524).

Comment: Somewhy I thought the app is not free. Sorry, my mistake... Somewhy with the latest IntelliJ I get strange errors, so I have to use a previous version of it.
But I think I will do it with the app, thanks!